# Python SRE bytecode

Tags: python, regex, python-internals

I've been wondering is there any official documentation on secret labs regular expression engine (standard `re` module, basically)? I couldnt find any. Srsly, this is kind of understandable:

```
>>> sre_compile._code(sre_parse.parse('a'), 0)
[INFO, 8, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 97, 0, LITERAL, 97, SUCCESS]
```

and I wont hesitate to reverse engineer bytecode interpreter, yet somewhat like official documentation of any kind would be highly appreciated.

Comment: The best documentation is [the source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/sre_compile.py). Edit: opcodes have a translation [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/12d6b5d156377c0877931a03ef2439dccb2f3711/Lib/sre_constants.py)

Comment: Yes, I am aware about the code, thanks.

Comment: I would also be interested in this! Did you find anything out?